# Change activity in android program automatically at a given time

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timer

I want to move from an activity to another activity at a given time. How can I set this time for waiting in that page?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I am curious as to how you solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. There are several ways you can do this. For example, You can set up a Timer object and based on whatever criteria, set up a task to call `startActivity()` to do the switch. Or you can use a Handler and use the `postDelayed()` method to accomplish the same thing. Simply set up the handler and the time delay and then in the runnable call `startActivity()`. However, unless you give a bit more information, it is sort of hard to give you the right solution. Can you give a bit more context on what you are trying to solve?

Maybe the below references can help
 - Timer:http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html
 - Handler:
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Building on what Lennon just suggested below, you can use and Event mechanism, like Otto or EventBus to trigger the `startActivity()` based on a particular event being fired.

- Otto:http://square.github.io/otto/
- EventBus: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `BroadcastReceiver` like the following:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#broadcastreceiver